# I was invited to meet

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which is correct in the following?

> I am invited to meet the president.
>
> I am invited to meet with the president.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. But there is still a nuance of meaning.

> I am invited to meet with the president. ( I have a meeting with the president) - the verb *meet* is
> intransitive(without object);

> Whereas in your first sentence: *the verb "meet"* is transitive(with
> object). ( most likely to mean = be in someone's presence );

Given that you are using the noun *"president"* and that word combination seems quite a bit more common to me, I would use *"to meet with someone"*.

for instance

*She and I have decided to **meet up(also intransitive)* later.**

This brings us to the conclusion that some verbs in English can be both intransitive and transitive with *little or no difference in meaning at all.*

Also, here are some stats from Ngrams:

[Meet the president vs meet with the president](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&corpus=26&content=meet%20with%20the%20president%2C%20meet%20the%20%20president%20&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeet%20with%20the%20president%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeet%20the%20president%3B%2Cc0)

According to ngrams, *"to meet the president"* is used slightly more often.

Comment: Personally I feel like *meet with* has more of a sense that you're both getting together to do something important - having a meeting with a purpose. Whereas *meet* on its own can just mean a social encounter, or something ceremonial or done for publicity. But it depends on who's speaking and how they normally phrase things.

Comment: @cactustictacs Well yeah. I can't deny that. I guess I was clear enough.

Comment: “Meet with” is currently controversial (except in sentences like “I expect this proposal to meet with some opposition”). It’s now in common usage, but you won’t find it in most dictionaries. “Meet” in this sense has historically been a transitive verb that doesn’t take a preposition. To express your nuance, you would say “I am invited to have a meeting with the President.”

Comment: Some dictionaries even say that "meet with" is chiefly American.....

Comment: My old copy of Practical English Usage from a decade ago mentions it in the "languages change over time" section, as an example of Am E phrases that have moved into Br E usage. I don't know, I like the sense of coming together for a purpose it adds? And grammatically it doesn't feel any different from "met opposition" vs "met *with* opposition"

Comment: @cactustictacs Sure. That's why I said "both are [grammatically] correct". But I also included ngrams research covering both BrE and AmE in my answer.

Comment: Oh I wasn't criticising your answer or anything! Just adding some thoughts, and pointing out that it's been in use here for a while too, so I don't know how "controversial" it is (that was responding to what Mike said, I guess I should have used the @ huh)

Comment: @cactustictacs Very well then. Thank you for your feedback.